# How to play a a sound from the app resources folder on button press, with AudioKit?

Tags: audiokit

I  I'm trying to play a random sound from the app resources folder in an iOS app.

I am using AudioKit v5 `v5-main` branch, and Swift 5.3 on XCode 12.  The app builds but crashes when I press the play button in the UI; the error is listed below the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

...

// For audio playback
let engine = AudioEngine()
let player = AudioPlayer()
let mixer = Mixer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  ...
    
    // Initialize AudioKit pipeline
    mixer.addInput(player)
    engine.output = mixer
    do {
        try engine.start()
    } catch let err {
        print(err)
    }
}

@IBAction func playButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    playSound()
}


func playSound() {
    let randomSound = sounds.randomElement()
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: randomSound, withExtension: "wav")
    
    print("URL: \(url)")
    // player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
    player.scheduleFile(url!, at: nil)
    player.play()
            
}
```

}

The error produced when the button is pressed is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: _outputFormat.channelCount == buffer.format.channelCount'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I believe that I may be failing to initialize the audio engine properly, but I'm not sure how/where to do that.  Any pointers?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. Good question!